# Generate textbox with an addon button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

in ASP.NET MVC I want to generate this kind of textbox:

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic

http://screencast.com/t/u1WjajPTDC76

The code I am using is the following:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPrincipalName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPrincipalName)
     <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@Html.Label(xx.Utils.SettingsHelper.Domain)</span>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPrincipalName)
   </div>
 </div>
```

However the behavior I get is not the

http://screencast.com/t/DV7VGtVakbSY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `<div class="form-group">` but it must be `<div class="input-group">`